# Installed 12.04 and my head set mic is not recognized

Tags: sound, microphone, headset

The mic was recognized in the earlier version and I was able to use it. But after the upgrade, I have not been able to use my head set mic. I went to the sound settings for input and it is not listed there.  The head set is listed in output.

Answer (score 1):

Please try typing 'alsamixer' into a terminal. You may be able to see if your mic is muted from there.

Comment: Having the same issue, no help in alsamixer.

Comment: Update corrected problem at time, now I have 14.04 and everything works great.